# Download a file from a url present in a txt file with python 2.7.9

Tags: file, url, text, download, wget

i have writed this script below for python 3 this works great with python 3 but with python 2 this script just doesn't work, do you know any method to make it work with python 2.7.9?

```html
import wget

with open ("abcd_url.txt", encoding='utf-8', mode = 'r') as f:
    for url in f.readlines():
        filename = wget.download(url.strip())
        print (filename)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use this [3to2](https://wiki.python.org/moin/3to2). It will convert it.